# Using resources in Android freezes the main thread

Tags: java, android

I'm doing the Google Android App Course, and I encountered a weird error. If I call `initVariables()`, the layout is not appearing, if I comment it out, it appears. If I return after calling `getResources()`, I see the layout, if I return after calling `getString()`, no layout.

in the logcat i only see is some idle timeout reached.
i currently having some problems with my environment (eclipse crash and such), so i can't post a full logcat.
This is the code and the xml:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.advanced);
    initLayout();
    initVariables();
}

protected void initLayout() {
    m_vwJokeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addJokeButton);
    m_vwJokeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newJokeEditText);
    m_vwJokeLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.jokeListLayout);
}

protected void initVariables() {
    Resources resources = getResources();
    author = resources.getString(R.string.author_name);
    m_nDarkColor = resources.getColor(R.color.dark);
    m_nLightColor = resources.getColor(R.color.light);
    m_arrJokeList = new ArrayList<Joke>();
}
```

layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/InputLayoutViewGroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addJokeButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Joke" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/newJokeEditText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/jokeListViewGroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/jokeListLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: May be some exception caused during `initVariables()` being invoked?

Comment: Are there any logcat messages when you run it?

Comment: please post Logcat and your advanced.xml

Comment: Is this in the emulator or on a device?

Comment: device. if i try to load an emulator on my computer it will die.

Answer (score 0):

If R.string.author_name isn't found at runtime, I'll be throwing an exception. You could catch the exception

```
    try {
        author = resources.getString(R.string.author_name);
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {

    }
```

but the question should really be why is your R.string.author_name missing? Are you able to successfully get any string resources?